# Regular Expression problem (in asp.net MVC5)

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

hoping someone can point out what I'm missing here with a regular expression.

Here is the data item from my model :-

```
[Display(Name = "Serial to Search")]
[MaxLength(12)]
[RegularExpression(@"ABC|WXYZ\w{8,9}")]
public string SerialNo { get; set; }
```

This should allow me to match a serial that begins with either ABC or WXYZ and has another 8 or 9 characters/numbers.

In my view I'm using jquery unobtrusive validation and an @Html.ValidationMessageFor control to display errors.

I have tested this on regex101.com using the following test string :-

```
ABCGC1000BC5
```

and it passes fine, but in my view I get a validation error, specifically that the string doesn't match the regex requirements. Can anyone see what I'm missing ? Thanks.

[regex101.com screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ad3F.png)

Comment: Use a grouping, `(ABC|WXYZ)\w{8,9}`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I can't believe it was that. Many thanks. Please add this as a solution so that I can accept it. And thanks for the lightening fast reply.

Comment: Posted below. I suggest using the non-capturing version, as best practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex matches two type of strings: 1) `ABC` or 2) `WXYZ` followed with 8 or 9 word chars. Remember that `RegularExpressionAttribute` pattern must match the whole string. Even if regex101.com shows a match for `ABC12`, it won't match in your environment.

You need to use a grouping,

```
(ABC|WXYZ)\w{8,9}
^        ^
```

A non-capturing group would fit even better since you are only validating a string and not using captures later:

```
(?:ABC|WXYZ)\w{8,9}
^^^        ^
```

Answer (score 1):

`RegularExpressionAttribute` searches for an exact match: if the Regex isn't anchored to beginning or end of the string, then `RegularExpressionAttribute` will effectively do that anchoring for you. [See the implementation on ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/RegularExpressionAttribute.cs,59).

That is the difference between regex101.com and your test where it fails. If you anchor the regex on regex101.com, as `^ABC|WXYZ\w{8,9}$`, you will see that it fails.

The reason, as Wiktor Stribiżew pointed out in the comments, is that your regex looks for `ABC` OR `WXYZ\w{8,9}`. Neither `^ABC$` nor `^WXYZ\w{8,9}$` match your test string of `ABCGC1000BC5`.

**Edit:** (Please accept Wiktor Stribiżew's answer as the solution. This answer just aims to explain the difference between running it on regex101.com and in ASP.NET).

Comment: Thanks @canton7 for that explanation, very useful.